# Arquillian Drone completely ignores Before After BeforeClass AfterClass annotations

Tags: webdriver, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to use [Arquillian Drone](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Drone) to driver my tests, however, for some reason **annotations `@Before`, `@After`, `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` are completely ignored**.

I'm new to this Java/jUnit/Arquillian environment (always been working with Python), so I might be making some stupid mistake here.

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Drone;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


import com.eyereturn.warlock.client.pages.login.LoginPage;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestDroneLogin {

    @Drone
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testInput(){
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#gbqfq"));
    }
}
```

**arquillian.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <extension qualifier="webdriver">
        <property name="browserCapabilities">chrome</property>
    </extension>

</arquillian>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproj</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-integration-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project Integration Tests</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>      
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.31.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Arquillian Core dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Arquillian Drone dependencies and Selenium dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
          <type>pom</type>
          <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Arquillian Graphene Webdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Alpha3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Arquillian JUnit Standalone -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is an ongoing problem with [Arquillian Standalone](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA2/Framework+Integration+Options) version.

the bug is open [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1070?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel), **however has not received any attention since August 14, 2012**.

The workaround is to use **"Arquillian JUnit Container"** version in `pom.xml` instead of "Arquillian JUnit Standalone":

```
    <!-- Arquillian JUnit Container -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This seems to work for me.

NOTE: When using `@BeforeClass` with `Drone` watch out the [this bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1340)